# Error show pdf CrystalReport vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have the code below
its function is to load the data from a report on the screen using the CrystalReports.

```
Dim strExportFile As String
            strExportFile = "ReportReajustesAplicados.pdf"

            Dim s As System.IO.MemoryStream = relat.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
            With HttpContext.Current.Response

                .ClearContent()
                .ClearHeaders()
                .ContentType = "application/pdf"
                .AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & strExportFile)
                .BinaryWrite(s.ToArray)
                .End()
            End With
```

When I do the extraction of the data.

I have the following error

**Unable to cast object of type 'FileStreamDeleteOnClose' to type 'System.IO.MemoryStream'.**

I tried using System.IO.Stream, extraction works but does not display the data on the screen because ".BinaryWrite (s.ToArray)" does not accept the method ToArray.

Note: When I put

```
#if DEBUG Then
             CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = relat
             CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind ()
             Exit Sub

If #End
```

works

I need this to work but in Release mode.

Help me

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution on:

https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3322762

As answered by SAP guy:
"This is by design, we never fully supported export to MemoryStream.
Only option is to not use MemoryStream, this will not be changed."

So the solution is to replace **MemoryStream** with **Stream** and send it in **Byte** array as in:

```
Dim strExportFile As String
strExportFile = "ReportReajustesAplicados.pdf"
Dim s As System.IO.Stream = relat.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
Dim b(s.Length) As Byte
s.Read(b, 0, CInt(s.Length))

With HttpContext.Current.Response
    .ClearContent()
    .ClearHeaders()
    .ContentType = "application/pdf"
    .AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & strExportFile)
    .BinaryWrite(b)
    .Flush()
    .SuppressContent = True
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
End With
```

Comment: I had the same problem. This way work to me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**try to use this code to convert in stream:**

```
//MemoryStream oStream = (MemoryStream)reportDocument.ExportToStream(type);
System.IO.Stream oStream = null;
byte[] byteArray = null;
oStream = reportDocument.ExportToStream(type);
byteArray = new byte[oStream.Length];
oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length - 1));
```

**here is the full code as reference:**

```
private void ShowReports(ReportDocument reportDocument, string fileName)
        {
            string rptType = GetQsSValue("ReportType");
            ExportFormatType type = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
            string rptTypeExt = string.Empty;
            string contentType = string.Empty;

            if (rptType == null || rptType == "PDF")
            {
                type = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                rptTypeExt = ".pdf";
                contentType = "application/pdf";
            }
            else if (rptType == "Excel" || rptType == "Text")
            {
                type = ExportFormatType.Excel;
                rptTypeExt = ".xls";
                contentType = "application/excel";               
            }

            //MemoryStream oStream = (MemoryStream)reportDocument.ExportToStream(type);
            System.IO.Stream oStream = null;
            byte[] byteArray = null;
            oStream = reportDocument.ExportToStream(type);
            byteArray = new byte[oStream.Length];
            oStream.Read(byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(oStream.Length - 1));

            reportDocument.Close();
            reportDocument.Dispose();
            reportDocument = null;

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + rptTypeExt);
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(oStream.ToArray());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            GC.Collect();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `.BinaryWrite(s.ToArray)` by `.BinaryWrite(CType(Session("myCrystalReport"), IO.MemoryStream).ToArray())`.

I wrote an example below, I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I hope it can help you. This works for me to let users download/view Crystal Reports using the PDF format.

```
 Dim fileName As String = "ReportReajustesAplicados.pdf"
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
 Response.Clear()
 Response.Buffer = True
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + fileName)
 Response.BinaryWrite(CType(Session("myCrystalReport"), IO.MemoryStream).ToArray())
 Response.End()
```

I put the Crystal report in the session with those options (rpt is my Crystal Report):

```
Dim options = rpt.ExportOptions
options.ExportFormatType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
Session!myCrystalReport= rpt.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportRequestContext With {
        .ExportInfo = options
        })
rpt.Dispose()
```

If my answer is unclear or is not what you were looking for, please tell me and I will try to update it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem when running locally. Instead of using a stream, use this:

```cs
using (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument oRpt =
    new ReportDocument())    
{    
    oRpt.Load(Server.MapPath("../RptFiles/MyCReport.rpt"));   
    oRpt.SetDataSource(MyDataSource);  

    // ... other stuff you need, params, etc  

    Response.Clear();                  
    Response.ClearHeaders();

    oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, false,
        "MyReportName");

    oRpt.Close();    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are not working with web servers and just need to save it:

```
Dim myStream As New System.IO.MemoryStream

'ExportToStream acutally produces type: FileStreamDeleteOnClose -- not Stream.  Can't implicitly convert it to MemoryStream   
Dim myTempStream As System.IO.Stream
myTempStream = oRpt.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)

'Now copy the data to a MemoryStream before closing the report and destroying the stream.
myTempStream.CopyTo(myStream)

'Clean up and close the temp stream and report.
oRpt.Close()
```